# Split array values, which is the best path to give data?

Tags: php, algorithm, php-5.3

I have this array (can't be changed):

```
Array
(
    [0] => AGUI vs CARI Hora 7:30 pm</span></p>PUERTO LA CRUZ</span></p>
    [1] => MAGA vs LEON Hora 7:30 pm</span></p>CARACAS</span></p>
    [2] => BRAV vs TIGR Hora 7:30 pm</span></p>MARACAY</span></p>
    [3] => TIBU vs CARD Hora 7:30 pm</span></p>BARQUISIMETO</span></p>
)
```

and I need to split to get values separately, for example for this:

```
[0] => AGUI vs CARI Hora 7:30 pm</span></p>PUERTO LA CRUZ</span></p>
```

I need to split into:

```
AGUI vs CARI
7:30 pm (I not need the word "Hora")
PUERTO LA CRUZ
```

I've tried to replace `</span></p>` by using this:

```
str_replace("</span></p>", "-", trim($the_string_var));
```

and clean a bit more strings but it doesn't work, can any give me some tips or ideas for this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did my little best ;)

```
<?php
$str="AGUI vs CARI Hora 7:30 pm</span></p>PUERTO LA CRUZ</span></p>";
$str=str_replace(array(' vs ',' Hora ','</span></p>'),'XXX',$str);
$arr=explode('XXX',$str);
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value)
    if (empty($value))
        unset($arr[$key]);
print_r($arr); //If you want it seperately, then access it like $arr[0],$arr[1],...
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array ( [0] => AGUI [1] => CARI [2] => 7:30 pm [3] => PUERTO LA CRUZ )
```

Comment: Amazing, it works perfectly but now I need to split also `AGUI vs CARI` so result should be `Array ( [0] => AGUI [1] => CARI [2] => 7:30 pm, [3] => PUERTO LA CRUZ )`, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 $var =  AGUI vs CARI Hora 7:30 pm</span></p>PUERTO LA CRUZ</span></p>

 $fvar = explode('Hora',$var);
 $svar = explode('</span></p>',$fvar[1]);

 echo $fvar[0];   //contains AGUI vs CARI
 echo $svar[0];   //contains 7:30 pm
 echo $svar[1];   //PUERTO LA CRUZ
```